# NodeJS npm install LDAP-client Error Code 1

Tags: node.js, ldap, openldap, ldap-client

After installing `openldap-devel`, my error still exists.

I am running on Linux 3.10.0-514.6.1.el7.x86_64. This is a big hurdle for me to install the ldap-client package using `npm install`. Could someone help with me on this? I cannot install `libldap2-dev` on the Linux using `yum`. But I have successfully installed these two packages: `sudo yum install python-devel` and `sudo yum install openldap-devel`. It looks like `apt-get` is only for Debian/Ubuntu for installing `libldap2-dev`. I have run out of ideas, and it took me way longer to deploy the system.

```
ldap-client@3.1.3 install Project/node_modules/ldap-client
node-gyp rebuild
make: Entering directory /home/Workspace/slack-weare/node_modules/ldap- 
client/build' CXX(target) Release/obj.target/LDAPCnx/LDAP.o In file 
included from ../LDAP.cc:2:0: ../LDAPCnx.h:5:18: fatal error: ldap.h: 
No such file or directory compilation terminated. make: *** 
[Release/obj.target/LDAPCnx/LDAP.o] Error 1
```

I have done some homework.

https://github.com/linkedin/oncall/issues/130

https://github.com/digicoop/kaiwa/issues/4

https://github.com/kvspb/nginx-auth-ldap/issues/5

https://github.com/kvspb/nginx-auth-ldap/issues/156

https://github.com/kvspb/nginx-auth-ldap/issues/48